# How to correct write test with async methods?

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-4.5, async-await

I have class for iterating images.

```
public class PictureManager
    {
        private int _current;
        public List<BitmapImage> _images = new List<BitmapImage>(5);
        public static string ImagePath = "dataImages";

        public async void LoadImages()
        {
            _images = await GetImagesAsync();
        }
        public async Task<List<BitmapImage>> GetImagesAsync()
        {
            var files = new List<BitmapImage>();
            StorageFolder picturesFolder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("dataImages");
            IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> itemsList = await picturesFolder.GetItemsAsync();
            foreach(var item in itemsList)
            {
                if(!(item is StorageFile)) continue;
                var tempImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(item.Path));
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("add {0}", item.Path));
                files.Add(tempImage);
            }
            return files;

        }
}
```

And I write this test method(I use nUnit):

```
  [TestFixture]
    public class PictureManagerTest
    {
        private PictureManager _pic;

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            _pic = new PictureManager();
            _pic.LoadImages();

        }

        [Test]
        public void ElementOfImagesIsNotNull()
        {
            _pic.GetImagesAsync().ContinueWith(r =>
            {
                BitmapImage image = r.Result[0];
                image = null;
                Assert.IsNotNull(image);
            });
        }
}
```

Why this test is successful?

Comment: Have a look at these posts: http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-2-right-way.html and http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html

Comment: I think that it's problem with nUnit. Same problem [link](http://anthonysteele.co.uk/async-and-await-with-nunit)

Comment: AsyncUnitTests-MSTest 1.0.1 don't work with .net 4.5
`Could not install package 'AsyncUnitTests-MSTest 1.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5'`

Comment: @Victor: The `AsyncUnitTests-MSTest` project only applies to VS2010 MSTest projects. You're using nUnit on VS2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nUnit, as of right now, doesn't directly support asynchronous tests (MSTest and xUnit do, however).

You can work around this by waiting on the results, like so:

```
    [Test]
    public void ElementOfImagesIsNotNull()
    {
        var continuation = _pic.GetImagesAsync().ContinueWith(r =>
        {
            BitmapImage image = r.Result[0];
            image = null;
            Assert.IsNotNull(image);
        });

        // Block until everything finishes, so the test runner sees this correctly!
        continuation.Wait();
    }
```

The second option, of course, would be to use something like MSTest, which does support testing asynchronous code, ie:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task ElementOfImagesIsNotNull()
    {
        var images = await _pic.GetImagesAsync();

        BitmapImage image = r.Result[0];
        image = null;
        Assert.IsNotNull(image);
    }
```

Comment: Note that waiting on the tests will wrap any exceptions in an `AggregateException`, so "expected failure" tests will require more work.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes - very good point.  You'd have to unroll the `AggregateException` and rethrow the first inner exception, or manage it yourself.

Comment: yes, i have this `System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
  ----> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
  ----> System.Exception : The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))`

Comment: @Victor That's actually a different issue - you must be doing something with the image you're pulling, right?

Comment: @Victor the problem is that BitmapImage has thread affinity, so you can't use it from other threads.  As such, it's difficult to use in async scenarios, and even harder in unit tests where you don't have a UI-based synchronization context.

Comment: As of release 2.6.2 NUnit supports async test methods.