# unexpected async await behavior in mstest unit test

Tags: testing, asynchronous, mstest, async-await

I'm having newbie problems testing an async method. I've read a few other posts, including [How to correct write test with async methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625595/how-to-correct-write-test-with-async-methods?rq=1), and I *think* I'm doing things correctly, but I'm clearly missing something.

Here's the code I'm trying to test:

```
/// <summary>
/// Temporary method used to simulate the time required to generate a report.
/// </summary>
public virtual async Task GenerateTestReportAsync()
{
    ++ActiveTaskCounter;

    await Task.Delay(2000);

    --ActiveTaskCounter;
}
```

And here's the test (yes, I could/should improve it by storing the ActiveTaskCounter values in a list, but that's beside the point):

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GenerateTestReportAsyncUpdatesActiveTaskCounter()

    var bayViewModel = CreateBayViewModel();

    var invocationCount = 0;
    bayViewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == "ActiveTaskCounter")
            {
                ++invocationCount;
            }
        };

    await bayViewModel.GenerateTestReportAsync();

    //Thread.Sleep(2100); // TODO: Why is this needed?
    Assert.AreEqual(2, invocationCount);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, bayViewModel.ActiveTaskCounter);
}
```

The test always passes with the Thread.Sleep uncommented. It always fails with the Thread.Sleep commented, as shown above. Why is this? I assumed the code below the "await bayViewModel.GenerateTestReportAsync()" wouldn't even execute until GenerateTestReportAsync was *really* finished.

BTW, I'm using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709

Thanks for any help you can provide! This has me stumped :-|

EDIT: Here's a minimal repro of the view model class...

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class BayViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public BayViewModel()
    {
        PropertyChanged = (sender, args) => { };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _activeTaskCounter;
    public int ActiveTaskCounter
    {
        get
        {
            return _activeTaskCounter;
        }
        set
        {
            _activeTaskCounter = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ActiveTaskCounter"));
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task GenerateTestReportAsync()
    {
        ++ActiveTaskCounter;

        await Task.Delay(2000);

        --ActiveTaskCounter;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks correct to me. Can you create a minimal repro?

Comment: I'll update the original question with the repro...

Comment: It gets even more strange! The repro code worked! I saw that repro project was using version 10.1.0.0 of Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll, whereas my original project was using version 10.0.0.0. I changed my original project to use the same version as the repro. No change :-(. Note that the GenerateTestReportAsync() and ActiveTaskCounter implementations are identical between the two. The test is identical as well.

Comment: You are definitely seeing something weird...

Comment: Thanks, Stephen, for confirming that at least the async stuff is right! Now I guess I've got to figure which assembly in this mix of assemblies is causing this strangeness (sigh - there goes any hope of productivity).

Comment: Of your two assertions, which one fails and what is the actual value?

Comment: The first one fails, and then the test is over.

Comment: A coworker of mine figured it out. Yes, I'm a total moron. In my test class I'm using an instance of a "test double" class that overrides that method. Here's a snip of the original implementation (pardon the formatting) <snip>if (GenerateAssayTestReportStub == null) { await Task.FromResult(base.GenerateAssayTestReport());</snip>. And here's the correction: <snip>if (GenerateAssayTestReportStub == null) { var task = Task.FromResult(base.GenerateAssayTestReport()); await task; // Await the outer/wrapper task. await task.Result; // Await the inner/target task.</snip>. Sorry for wasting your time!